# Not show a full row if a query is not a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to not show whole row if the "payment_method" that I am displaying is not of value'x'. How can I update my code to do so?

```
SELECT
    p.ID AS order_id,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS user_ID,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_total,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS payment_method

FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status = 'wc-completed'
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

Comment: I think you want a `having` clause.

Comment: It aids comprehension if you always qualify all columns, including those in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `HAVING` clause. Much like `WHERE` clause that filters your record set BEFORE aggregation (and often times before joining even) a `HAVING` clause filters the result set after aggregation. It's one of the last steps to run in your SQL:

```
SELECT
    p.ID AS order_id,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS user_ID,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS order_total,
    max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_payment_method' AND p.ID = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS payment_method

FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status = 'wc-completed'    
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING payment_method <> 'X'
```

Comment: This is throwing an error on the GROUP BY p.ID and is not working. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps the `HAVING` clause must come AFTER the `GROUP BY`. I have updated the answer. Let me know if that doesn't fix it.